# Google home action account link failed

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

Account linking problem for only some of our users, most users link account normally.  For users linking account failed, they just see the login page refreshed to empty account name and password.

From our server log, we found for users that fail to link, the user accesses our server successfully and got OAUTH code, but after about 15 seconds, google server accessed our server to exchange the code for a token. However, the code has expired by this time.

For successfully linked users,  the time between issuing the code and exchanging it for a token is about 2 seconds.

Does anybody know how to resolve the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: The question is on topic for the subject.

Comment: is the time on your server correct?

Comment: We checked the time, it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question showing the settings for the token you are using to connect to your auth server with.   What values do you have set for [AuthorizationCodeLifetime] [AccessTokenLifetime] [AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime]

Comment: AuthorizationCodeLifetime is 7 days, AccessTokenLifetime is 1 month,  AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime is 3 months。 Our  OAuth server didn't return code expire error to Google.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the expiration time for the authorization code has been set to about 10-15 seconds. While the auth code should have a short lifetime, 10 seconds is *way* too short. The [recommended lifetime](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) should be no more than 10 minutes, not 10 seconds.

Consider that this code needs to be sent back from your server to the user, from the user to Google, and then from Google to your server. On some networks, each step might take more than a couple of seconds, particularly since it must be done over HTTPS this adds both network and processing overhead. Each step adds just a few fractions of a second - but they can add up on some devices!

There could also be a slight clock skew between the issuing server and the processing server - likely not much, but when you have a lifetime of a just a few seconds, even a 1 second skew could be too much. If the two are very out of skew, then this could be the cause of your problem as well. Make sure the clocks on your servers are at least reasonably in sync.

The best solution would be to increase this timeout on your server when you generate or accept the code. You may have thought you were specifying 10 minutes for a configuration field that actually accepts seconds.

Comment: As noted by @DaimTo, clock skew is also a likely possibility. By itself, a large skew could be a problem. A small skew would compound the problem of a small code lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We checked our server time, it is correct.  And our code expiration time is 7 days, our server returned token by code to Google server correctly.

Comment: I'm confused. You stated "the code has expired by this time", meaning after 15 seconds. If the code expires after 7 days - how is it also expiring after 15 seconds? Can you update your original question to be more clear about what is happening and what you're seeing?  (And 7 days is WAY too long for the code to be valid.)

Comment: My original word is "the time is too long".  Sorry for not stated clear as English is not my mother tongue.  Google first call our api to get OAUTH code, our server returned correctly and fast. Then after about 15 seconds, Google call our api again to exchange for OATUH token by code, our server also returned correctly and fast, our server didn't return code expire error to Google. In fact based on these, I can only defer maybe Google Home server or APP has some problem for some user request?